# Populating a SwiftUI view with output from a combine publisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

How do I get the data returned from a combine publisher, to a view?

[image]

There are many examples of this that show sink -> print. There is nothing that clearly shows how to do anything other than print.

Comment: Make a State variable to put suite into then it goes to the body from there.

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out assign(to:) only works for publishers that return a single value, so you need to ignore the error one way or another. You can add `.assertNoFailure()` or `replaceError(with:)`.

I suppose if we wanted to handle the error, then we would need to put this into an object with a sink and then assign some local properties with the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
@State var text = ""
var some View{
   Text(text)
    .padding()
    .onAppear(perform: {
        client.sink(receiveValue:{ value in 
        text = value
    }
  })
}
```